# Retrieve shapefile from ESRI ArcServer (proxy.ashx)

Tags: dojo, geojson, shapefile, arcgis-server

Alberta has an ESRI map about the Oil Sands (OSIP): [Link](http://osip.alberta.ca/map/).

When you save the webpage you will get an proxy.ashx file which seems to contain the whole geometry:

> dojo.io.script.jsonp_dojoIoScript9._jsonpCallback({"displayFieldName":"Operator_Name","fieldAliases":{"OBJECTID":"OBJECTID","OSP_NO":"Project
>   Number","Project_Name":"Project Name","OS_Area":"Oil Sands
>   Area","Industry_Type":"Industry Type","Project_Status":"Project
>   Status","Year":"Year","Shape.STArea()":"Shape.STArea()","Shape.STLength()":"Shape.STLength()","Operator_Name":"Operator
>   Name"},"geometryType":"esriGeometryPolygon","spatialReference":{"wkid":102100,"latestWkid":3857},"fields":[{"name":"OBJECTID","type":"esriFieldTypeOID","alias":"OBJECTID"},{"name":"OSP_NO","type":"esriFieldTypeSmallInteger","alias":"Project
>   Number"},{"name":"Project_Name","type":"esriFieldTypeString","alias":"Project
>   Name","length":255},{"name":"OS_Area","type":"esriFieldTypeString","alias":"Oil
>   Sands
>   Area","length":5},{"name":"Industry_Type","type":"esriFieldTypeString","alias":"Industry
>   Type","length":3},{"name":"Project_Status","type":"esriFieldTypeString","alias":"Project
>   Status","length":3},{"name":"Year","type":"esriFieldTypeSmallInteger","alias":"Year"},{"name":"Shape.STArea()","type":"esriFieldTypeDouble","alias":"Shape.STArea()"},{"name":"Shape.STLength()","type":"esriFieldTypeDouble","alias":"Shape.STLength()"},{"name":"Operator_Name","type":"esriFieldTypeString","alias":"Operator
>   Name","length":75}],"features":[{"attributes":{"OBJECTID":1,"OSP_NO":1,"Project_Name":"Cold
>   Lake
>   Operations","OS_Area":"CL","Industry_Type":"02","Project_Status":"01","Year":2015,"Shape.STArea()":688184465.74006724,"Shape.STLength()":193203.94833874877,"Operator_Name":"Imperial
>   Oil
>   Resources"},"geometry":{"rings":[[[-12282289.675502496,7273922.0817552721],[-12282396.117050292,7273922.0677068951],
>   ...CONTENT... 
>   ]]]}}]});

(Full paste [available here](https://paste.ee/p/wghaH))

Is there any way to export this as a shapefile?

PS: Would be great, if the proxy file could be used to circumvent ESRIs strategy to hide the geometry in SVG paths.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [AGStoShapefile](https://github.com/tannerjt/AGStoShapefile) from TannerGeo for this task.

Answer (score 0):

I think this Link could solve your Problem to convert GeoJson to Shape.

https://community.esri.com/thread/105193

It matches your Question perfectly.

Regards, Miriam